# Kotlin Multiplatform gradle Java version issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I would like to compile a library for iOS and Android the build.gradle file below. It works for iOS (if I remove androidTarget (+ com.android.library plugin), however I'm not able to compile it also for Android. If I try it with Settings > Build... > Build Tools >  Gradle JVM 17 I face this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugKotlinAndroid'. > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

If I try it with Settings > Build... > Build Tools > Gradle JVM 15 it no longer syncs the gradle with this error

> Gradle JVM version incompatible. This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 15 but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17.

I tried several different combinations but without success so far, any hel is much appreciated.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.9.10"
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.2"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

kotlin {

    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
    }

   iosX64 {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "test"
                linkerOpts += "-ld64"
            }
        }
    }

    iosArm64 {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "test"
                linkerOpts += "-ld64"
            }
        }
    }

    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isArm64 = System.getProperty("os.arch") == "aarch64"
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" && isArm64 -> macosArm64("native")
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" && !isArm64 -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" && isArm64 -> linuxArm64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" && !isArm64 -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 33
}
```

Comment: What version of Gradle you are using? Try defining jvmTarget explicitly. Also check JDK settings in for the Compiler and in the Project Structure menu.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added this code,jdk 21 is installed in my machine but project using java version 18 in my project so I have set jvmToolChain = 18. and issue is resolved.

(if you are using kts then add this in buildSrc gradle file)

kotlin {
jvmToolchain(18)
}

hope this will help some if this is the case.